# Vertical alignment in column content in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

I am trying to horizontally align 3 columns (Bootstrap) that have variable heights depending on the size of the view port. As seen on the first picture, everything is centered and aligned on large screens.

[image]
When the viewport becomes smaller, the paragraph's height changes and the alignment is lost. I would like to keep the headings (blue), paragraphs, and buttons aligned.

My inital thought was to create three rows for the three different types of elements. Unfortunately I will not be able to do that since I want to keep the border in the middle column.

[image]

What would be a correct way of keeping alignment of these three columns regardless of the viewport size?

Comment: You mean to keep the buttons on the same line, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never really seen a perfect answer to this, thats not with javascript, I can't remember the exact code, however, last time i did it, i placed the text in a nested section, each boxes text section had the same class, and i assigned a min-height to that class that was long enough that it fitted the longest piece of text in, then place the button underneath that section.

If you put your code in a JSFiddle i can help you more, however,

it should looks something like this, layout wise,

```
<div class="four columns">
    <img></img>

    <div class="text">  this will have a min height 
    </div>

    <input>button here</input>
</div>
```

I hope this helps, i know it doesn't seem very clear, if you have a live version or a JSfiddle i'm more than happy to help further.

as for the text, you're very limited, there is some very good jquery scripts, just look through http://www.unheap.com

and just have general play with text sizes

Comment: I Just did a quick look for you on google,

Although we tend to build mobile first these days, if you get the text to look right with font sizes on a medium or large screen, then this script will help you scale it down and work on there :) 

https://github.com/jbrewer/Responsive-Measure

Have fun, Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are in an inline containe `vertical-align:middle;`